# Printing Based on Cell Contents in Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a workbook with around 200+  worksheets

I want to print specific sheets depending upon value in cell of that sheets.

I have tried:

```
Sub Printsheet()
  Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
  p = Worksheets.Count
  For q = 43 To p - 2
    With Worksheets(q)
      If Range("J35").Value > 0 Then
        .Worksheets.PrintOut from:=1, to:=1 'Prints page 1 when there is no data.
      Else
    End With
  Next q
End Sub
```

Getting error:

[image]

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: will keep in mind

Comment: This question can't be answered as question is too unclear :( so my answer is as broad as your question. Use vba,  detect cell value and then write code to print the given page

Comment: "Getting error" Sigh. What error? On what line? We are not mind readers or psychic ...

Comment: Error is with End With line " Compile Error End With Without With "

Comment: No VBA exprt here, but `Else End with`?  Seems a lost else.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your error first - then describe what's happening that's not supposed to happen

```
With Worksheets(q)
  If Range("J35").Value > 0 Then
    .Worksheets.PrintOut from:=1, to:=1 'Prints page 1 when there is no data.
  ' **Replace This**
  'Else
  ' ** With This**
  End If
End With
```